# write a MACRO for QString(_T("some text"))

Tags: c++, qt, macros

I would like to define a macro in C++ for

`QString(_T("some text"))`

for example: `QST("some text")`.

Should I write a method for that? Thank you for your help!

Comment: there is already the tr method in QObject, and QStringLiteral for the non-translated

Comment: In addition to above comment, macros are evil, better write an inline (possibly template) function.

Comment: Even better advice: `QString(L"Some Text")`. That also works on non-Windows systems.

Comment: yes, I would like to create a function, how can I do this? I am new in C++ sorry!